# How to use Scrapy for URL crawling

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to crawl the link `https://www.aparat.com/`.

I crawl it correctly and get all the video links with header tag;like this :

```
import scrapy
class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'aparatspider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.aparat.com/']
    def parse(self, response):
        print '=' * 80 , 'latest-trend :'
        ul5 = response.css('.block-grid.xsmall-block-grid-2.small-block-grid-3.medium-block-grid-4.large-block-grid-5.is-not-center')
        ul5 = ul5.css('ul').css('li')
        latesttrend = []
        for li5 in ul5:
           latesttrend.append(li5.xpath('div/div[1]/a').xpath('@onmousedown').extract_first().encode('utf8'))
           print(latesttrend)
```

now my question is this:

How can I get all the links from the `داغ ترین ها` tag, more than 1000? Currently, I get only 60, more or less.

Comment: Please share some examples of things you have already tried and where your code is at currently.

Comment: i edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this with the following code :

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.http import Request


class aparat_hotnewsItem(scrapy.Item):

      videourl = scrapy.Field()


class aparat_hotnewsSpider(CrawlSpider):
      name = 'aparat_hotnews'
      allowed_domains = ['www.aparat.com']
      start_urls = ['http://www.aparat.com/']

      # Xpath for selecting links to follow
      xp = 'your xpath'

      rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=xp), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
      )

      def parse_item(self, response):

      item = aparat_hotnewsItem()

      item['videourl'] = response.xpath('your xpath').extract()
      yield item
```